# 2nd exploded string to be a value to 1st exploded string in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php.. This is my problem: I have 2 exploded string, I want to make the 2nd exploded string to be the value of the 1st exploded string, the result of this I want    to insert in my database, but I don't have any problem with inserting.

For example, in the code below I want the $date to be a value to the $layer.
1st word of $layer is a value to 1st word of $date, 2nd word to 2nd word and so on..

```
$layer1=$_POST['layer'];

$date=$_POST['date'];

$layer=explode(",",$layer1);
$date=explode(",",$date);

foreach ($layer as $layer2=>$date )
{ 
//my problem is how to make the date a value to my layer?
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxx") or die ('unable to connect server');
mysqli_select_db($con, "xxxxxxxx") or die ('cant connect database');

$x="INSERT INTO xxxxx (Layer, date ) VALUES ('$layer2', '$date') ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$x) or die ('cant proceed query');


//i want to appear look like this on database:

LAYER       DATE
layer1      date1
layer2      date2
layer3      date3


say my data inputted from form is this one:

$_POST['layer']=layer1,layer2,layer3
$_POST['date']=date1,date2,date3
```

Comment: what does it mean "i want to make 2nd exploded string to be the value of the 1st exploded string"?

Comment: i already updated my question... i want something like that on my mysql table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxx", "xxxxxxxx");

$layer_arr = explode(",",$_POST['layer']);
$date_arr  = explode(",",$_POST['date']);

foreach ($layer_arr as $key => $layer )
{ 
    $date  = $date_arr[$key];
    $date  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $date);
    $layer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $layer);

    $sql   = "INSERT INTO xxxxx (Layer, date ) VALUES ('$layer', '$date') ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$x) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

please note that instead of manual formatting your strings you have to use placeholders in your query and thus use PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I just tried it and it works. I'll take your advice to use PDO.. :)